# Sending array variables using HTTParty

Tags: ruby, arrays, post, httparty

I'm sending a POST request using HTTParty. One of the variables required is an array. This is the code I'm using to send:

```
response = HTTParty.post url, :body => 
    {"key"=>'XYZ123',
    "content"=>
        [{"placename"=>"placeholder",
        "placecontent"=>"sample content"}],
    etc. }
```

The API needs to see:

```
"content": [
    {
        "placename": "placeholder",
        "placecontent": "sample content"
    }
],
```

However, when I check the request received logs on the API, I see that my code is producing:

```
"content": [
    {
        "placename": "placeholder"
    },
    {
        "placecontent": "sample content"
    }
],
```

How can I stop the array record from being split in two?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The desired output of the code is the equivalent of:

```
...&content[0][placename]=placeholder&content[0][placecontent]=sample%20content...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `HTTParty` uses [`HashConversions`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/HashConversions#to_params-class_method) to convert a `Hash` body to parameters:

> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> { :name => "Bob",
>   :address => {
>     :street => '111 Ruby Ave.',
>     :city => 'Ruby Central',
>     :phones => ['111-111-1111', '222-222-2222']
>   }
> }.to_params
>   #=> "name=Bob&address[city]=Ruby Central&address[phones][]=111-111-1111&address[phones][]=222-222-2222&address[street]=111
> ```
>
> Ruby Ave."

You can override this with your own convertor by using [`HTTParty.query_string_normalizer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/h/httparty2-0.7.10/HTTParty/ClassMethods.html#method-i-query_string_normalizer):

> Override the way query strings are normalized. Helpful for overriding
>   the default rails normalization of Array queries.
>
> For a query:
>
> ```
> get '/', :query => {:selected_ids => [1,2,3]}
> ```
>
> The default query string normalizer returns:
>
> ```
> /?selected_ids[]=1&selected_ids[]=2&selected_ids[]=3
> ```
>
> Let’s change it to this:
>
> ```
> /?selected_ids=1&selected_ids=2&selected_ids=3
> ```
>
> Pass a Proc to the query normalizer which accepts the yielded query.
>
> @example Modifying Array query strings
>
> ```
> class ServiceWrapper
>   include HTTParty
>
>   query_string_normalizer proc { |query|
>     query.map do |key, value|
>       value.map {|v| "#{key}=#{v}"}
>     end.join('&')
>   }
> end
> ```
>
> @param [Proc] normalizer custom query string normalizer. @yield [Hash,
>   String] query string @yieldreturn [Array] an array that will later be
>   joined with ‘&’

or simply pass it in your options:

```
response = HTTParty.post url, :body => 
    {"key"=>'XYZ123',
    "content"=>
        [{"placename"=>"placeholder",
        "placecontent"=>"sample content"}]},
    :query_string_normalizer => -> (h) { ... your own implementation here ...}
```

To get a serialization of `a[1]=val1&a[2]=val2` instead of `a[]=val1&a[]=val2` you can create your own `HashConversions` based on the [current one](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/hash_conversions.rb)

```
  class MyHashConversions

    def to_params(hash)
      params = hash.map { |k,v| normalize_param(k,v) }.join
      params.chop! # trailing &
      params
    end

    def normalize_param(key, value)
      param = ''
      stack = []

      if value.is_a?(Array)

        #### THE CHANGE IS HERE

        param << value.each_with_index.map { |element, i| normalize_param("#{key}[#{i}]", element) }.join

        ####
      elsif value.is_a?(Hash)
        stack << [key,value]
      else
        param << "#{key}=#{URI.encode(value.to_s, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))}&"
      end

      stack.each do |parent, hash|
        hash.each do |k, v|
          if v.is_a?(Hash)
            stack << ["#{parent}[#{k}]", v]
          else
            param << normalize_param("#{parent}[#{k}]", v)
          end
        end
      end

      param
    end
  end
```

The code above is not tested, but if it works, and is generic enough, you might consider forking the project and github, making the fix there, so it will work out of the box :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not sure how to apply this to my code. I'd be grateful for a concrete example of where/how this should be used with in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure how your encoded message should look - a default array encoding looks like `my_arr[]=val1&my_arr[]=val2...`, default hash encoding looks like `my_hash[k1]=v1&my_hash[k2]=v2`. A hash inside an array looks exactly as if there are multiple hashes with single keys - `content[][placecontent]=placeholder&content[][placename]=sample content`. How would you like it to look?

Comment: After trial and error to get the correct structure showing up in the API request logs, it looks like I need the third option - a hash inside an array. I've edited the question, adding on the desired encoded format.